# How to call android:onClick on xml button under another xml listview using fragment?

Tags: java, android, fragment

I tried this method and inflate home.xml in my HomeFragment.java:

```
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
        return root;
    }

    public void OnClickOnTransit(View v){
        final Button n = (Button) v;
        final String id = n.getTag().toString();

        AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        arrayAdapter.add("Tag as On Transit");
        arrayAdapter.add("Cancel");


        builderSingle.setAdapter(arrayAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                String strOption = arrayAdapter.getItem(which);
                if(strOption.equalsIgnoreCase("Tag as On Transit"))
                {
                    Tag_as_on_transit(id);
                }
                else if(strOption.equalsIgnoreCase("Cancel"))
                {
                    //confirmViewLeveling(emp_tag[1],emp_name.getText().toString());
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
        });
        builderSingle.show();

    }
```

Here is my home.xml where i put my listview.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_customer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And this is my nested_listview.xml where my button was placed.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_ontransit"
    android:layout_width="40dip"
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:background = "@drawable/ic_local_shipping_orange_24dp"
    android:textColor="#ff4500"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:onClick="OnClickOnTransit"/>
```

What i want is to call **OnClickOnTransit** from nested_listview.xml. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In that case your `parentActivity` must have this method

```
 public void OnClickOnTransit(View v){
}
```

However if you don't want that, You can implement like this in your fragment's `onViewcreated` method.

```
 Button btn_conferma = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_conferma);
       btn_conferma.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
       {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v)
                 {
                    // do something
                 } 
       });
```

Comment: Thanks this answer. I can`t call OnClickOnTransit in nested_listview.xml because it was not inflated in HomeFragment.java